# Pass parameter's datatype not consistent as it's declared

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift, I followed the treehouse lesson,

```
  let currentWeather = Current(weatherDictionary: weatherDictionary)
```

And don't know why I should use  `Current(weatherDictionary: weatherDictionary)` to pass compile

But not `Current(weatherDictionary: NSDictionary)`

Because I think I declared the  weatherDictionary as NSDictionary type

### Controller

```
  let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary =
      NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
  let currentWeather = Current(weatherDictionary: weatherDictionary)
```

### Current Struct

```
struct Current {
    var currentTime: String?
    var temperature: Int
    var humidity: Double
    var summary: String
    var icon: String

    init(weatherDictionary: NSDictionary){
```

Answer (score 0):

`weatherDictionary` is the name of your instance, that's why you need to use it.

You declared the parameter to be NSDictionary, but that's it. When using it using the named parameter (name: instance); the first parameter will be the name, and the second one will be the object instance wich needs to be of type NSDictonary.